# Bookmark to play a random YouTube playlist element

Tags: google-chrome, video, bookmarks, youtube

Using a link like this:
https://youtu.be/BxNpRi-ANWI?list=PL_PV1JilQxbgEv6zM9M105hrHfDZWls61&shuffle=119 
I can link to a video in a playlist and activate shuffle. But there are two problems here:

1. The shuffle order is always the same, since it's given a seed by the URL
2. It always starts at a specific video - this could be solved, if that is possible, by providing an index instead of a particular video, since I regularly add new playlist elements to the beginning of it.

I have the above link as a bookmark for my music playlist, and would like to fix these issues. I'm using Google Chrome, an extension is also an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please find documentation to youtube link parameters [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en) 
Check under the point Loading a playlist

I was able to link my metal playlist with the following link. The same link starts the same playlist on different videos, depending on which video I put first

www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PL-XZv_5_8hSR1RSKwXc027S-L8NRo5uLw

**Parameter:**

```
  https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLAYLIST_ID
```

Note that you need to prepend the playlist ID with the letters PL as shown in the following example:

```
 https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLC77007E23FF423C6
```

For some reason the playlists opens in full size... you have to check more for size parameters if you dont want this

I do not find any parameter for the shuffle option

Comment: "For some reason the playlists opens in full size" I know why, because what you provided is already known to me and supposed to be used for an HTML5 Player embedded in a Website(hence `embed` in the address bar), without loading any of the usual YouTube functionality. Unfortunately, that doesn't really solve my problem

Comment: I know it's not what you wanted, but I've been searching too long for this with no avail :
https://youtube-playlist-randomizer.bitbucket.io/ 
this works for me, because all I want is one click thing